# How function in python actually works?

Tags: python, function

I got a question for how a function actually works. From my understanding, the function can be call only if the call() is below the function which seems something like this :

```
def main():
     num1 = int(input("Please enter first number: "))
     print_num(num1)
main()
```

But I don't get it why the main() in print_num function can call the def main(), which locate under it.

```
def print_num(num1):
     print(num1)
     main()

def main():
     num1 = int(input("Please enter first number: "))
     print_num(num1)
main()
```

Comment: The code inside print_num is not evaluated until the function is run

Comment: The function/name needs to be defined *by the time it is __run__*, not by the time it’s *written*.

Comment: @Tom Python isn’t typically described as “compiled”, and this would work the same in Javascript too…

Comment: Check out the [Python - Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) documentation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your python code, only the function definition is read and the function name stored. The code inside the function is not evaluated until it has been called. So for example, the below when run will define the func1 and func2 then when it calls func1 only then the code of func1 is evaluated. At this point the code has already seen the func2 definition so its aware of it and there is no issue.

```
def func1():
    func2()


def func2():
    print("hello world")

func1()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hello world
```

However if we put the call to func1 before func2

```py
def func1():
    func2()

func1()

def func2():
    print("hello world")
```

In this case func1 is called before the code has even seen func2. So when it evaluates the code in func1 its no idea what func2 is and we get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cdoyle5/PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/chris.py", line 4, in <module>
    func1()
  File "C:/Users/cdoyle5/PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/chris.py", line 2, in func1
    func2()
NameError: name 'func2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def print_num(num1):
     print(num1)
     main()

def main():
     num1 = int(input("Please enter first number: "))
     print_num(num1)
main()
```

The above code is executed in the following order:

```
(1)def print_num(num1):
(6)     print(num1)
(7)     main()
(2)def main():
(4)     num1 = int(input("Please enter first number: "))
(5)     print_num(num1)
(3)main()
```

It's about the order in which it has been executed. So even if you write

```
def print_num(num1)
```

on line 1, it's body will be the 6th line of code to be executed, that is, only after it has been called. Python will only execute the body of a function after it has been called.

Comment: The `def` statement will be evaluated first, just the *function body* will be evaluated when called…!

Comment: @deceze right yes! I'll make the correction.